# Выравнивание ссылки по центру внутри блока, + адаптивность ссылки

Tags: html, scss

Как можно выравнять ссылку по центру, внутри блока так, чтобы ссылка не теряла адаптивность при изменении ширины блока?
Заранее всем спасибо

HTML:

```
 <div class="Catalog">
 <div class="GPU"><a href="#">Graphics Cards</a></div>
 <div class="MotherBoards"></div>
```

SCSS:

```
%ElementsCatalog {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 589px;
    position: relative;

}
.Catalog {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1980px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
}
.GPU {
    background-image: url(../Images/Images/GPU_IMG.jpg);
    @extend %ElementsCatalog;
}
.GPU a {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: "Intro", cursive;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        border: 3px solid #FF0000;
        font-size: 36px;

    }

.MotherBoards {
    background-image: url(../Images/Images/Motherboard_IMG.jpg);
    @extend %ElementsCatalog;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    .GPU a{
    font-size: 3vw;
    }
```

Фото для наглядности:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ссылка это GRAPHICS CARDS. Данная ссылка должна быть в центре блока .GPU

Comment: ```.GPU {display: flex; align-items:center; text-align: center; justify-content: center;}```

Answer (score 0):

`margin: auto`

```css
.center {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="center"></div>
```

`transform: translate();`

```css
.center {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="center"></div>
```

`width` и `height` + `calc();`

```css
.center {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 50px); /* ширины блока / 2 */
  top: calc(50% - 50px);  /* высота блока / 2 */
}
```

```html
<div class="center"></div>
```

`display: flex` ([@Pashok](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/985798/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8/985810#comment1661049_985798))

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*-------*/
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="center"></div>
```